# If IsNumeric(num) And Len(num) > 1 evaluates false for a number?

Tags: vba, excel

DUH, I figured it out I had Len(num) > 1 and the numbers in column A start at 0 to 9 and repeat.

```
     For r = 58 To 616

    num = Range("A" & r).Value
    If IsNumeric(num) And Len(num) > 0 Then

        Range("H" & r).Value = Range("I56").Value

        Range("I" & r).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=ABS(I54-H" & r & ")"
        Range("J" & r).Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=D" & r & "+(I55*I" & r & ")"
        Range("J" & r).Select                                   'Set value
    End If


Next r
```

Comment: that should read " I have mixed numbers, text and blanks"

Comment: what is `num`? how is it set? if it's dimmed as an int or long, there's no reason to use `isNumeric`

Comment: num = Range("A" & r).Value

Comment: sorry copy past error, missed that bit

Comment: you probably just want to say `if Len(num) > 0 then`

Comment: Then wouldn't it put a formula in a row if there was text there, if you just just Len

Comment: it's in a for loop, but I can't seem to figure out how to edit my question...lol and add the whole loop in

Comment: I did and I figured it out I had Len >1 so it would only work on numbers greater than 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to adjust it so that excel checks the range's `Value` for whether it's numeric instead of `num`. Also, you likely only want to check if the length is greater than 0, because that means something exists in the cell.

```
If IsNumeric(Range("A" & r).Value) And Len(Range("A" & r).Value) > 0 Then

    Range("H" & r).Value = Range("I56").Value

    Range("I" & r).Formula = "=ABS(I54-H" & r & ")"
    Range("J" & r).Formula = "=D" & r & "+(I55*I" & r & ")"

End If
```

Or if your variable `num` is already stored as an `Integer` or `Long` like below, you don't really need to do the `isNumeric()` check and, as @BigBen pointed out, `Long` and `Integer` variables will **always** evaluate to `Len() > 0`, so what you really want is to explicitly check that the number is greater than 0.

```
Dim num As Long
num = Range("A" & r).Value

If num > 0 Then

    Range("H" & r).Value = Range("I56").Value

    Range("I" & r).Formula = "=ABS(I54-H" & r & ")"
    Range("J" & r).Formula = "=D" & r & "+(I55*I" & r & ")"

End If
```

They both (should) do the same thing. You'll also notice that I got rid of the `.Select` calls in your code because [it's good practice to remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Note that `Len` of an `Integer` is always 2, and of a `Long` is always 4.

Comment: @BigBen may as well post that as an answer since it's the *actual* reason why OP's snippet wasn't working. I'll vote that baby up.

Comment: Well if `num` was a `Long` or `Int`, then `Len(num) > 0` (or 1, not sure based on the latest edit) would always be true. It's a useful point but not sure if it was the root problem.